# How do I not make JSOUP turn &ndash into a dash and &rsquo a quote rather than "?"

Tags: jsoup

I have success with making nbsp go to blank using "\00a0", but can't get the other two to be replaced.  I'm on a Sun OS box.

This is what I tried that works to replace &nbsp (need to be able to extend to other &n variables in html.

`doc.select("h1").toString().replace("\u00a0", " ").replace("\u0096", "-").replace("\u0092", "'");`

I've also tried (with various parameters)

`Jsoup.parse(myvariable, "UTF-8"));`
`doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);`
`doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");`

Nothing above seems to work.

Comment: I meant to say `How do I make JSOUP turn &ndash into a dash and &rsquo a quote rather than “?”`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this, in order to make your statement work, you should first use the .text() function to retrieve the text of the node.   Then from there, you should do a .replaceAll("\u00A0", " ").   Here is what i do to condition the output.   I have always felt that the characters should be treated more fairly like a space and dash like Selenium does in jsoup.   But, to get around, using the .text().replaceAll("\u00A0", " ") has always worked for me.